# 406 Not Acceptable Error accessing JSON on Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, authlogic

I want to show a list of users (UsersController#index) through either HTML or JSON in my Rails 3.1.3 app.

If not logged in, the HTML request should redirect to the login page, and the JSON request should return a 401 unauthorized header. The HTML request works perfectly. When not logged in, mysite.com/users redirects to the login page, and when logged in, mysite.com/users.json renders perfectly as JSON.

When not logged in, I get the 406 error when trying to access users.json, whether I check through the browser or through CURL (setting the content-type to 'application/json').

To check if a user is logged in, I use a before_filter, and authlogic for authentication. The thing is, if I remove the before_filter, the JSON request works perfectly. Which makes me think the problem is in my before_filter chain:

UsersController:

```
before_filter :login_required, :only => [:index]
```

AuthenticatedSystem (helper module):

```
def login_required
  logged_in? ? true : access_denied
end

def logged_in?
  current_user ? true : false #current_user does some authlogic authentication stuff
end

def access_denied
  respond_to do |accepts|
    accepts.html do
      store_location
      redirect_to login_path and return false
    end
    accepts.json do 
      render :json => {}, :status => :unauthorized
    end
  end
  false
end
```

And for reference here's the index method that is supposed to render the JSON:

```
def index
    @users = @users.active.recent.includes(:tags).page(params[:page]).per(20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { get_additional_homepage_data }
      format.json { render :json => @users }
    end
end
```

I've tried everything I could think of in my before_filter chain to debug this, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Using:
Rails 3.1.3
authlogic 3.1.0

Comment: Was this ever resolved? If so, please post your solution.

Comment: No, I never found the solution to this. A major refactor in the code helped me past this hurdle, but from my experience since then, I've realized the following heuristic is nearly always true: a 406 Not Acceptable error usually means you are trying to request a format that is not supported. So, check the URL you are calling (did you forget the .json at the end?), check the controller that handles the request (Did you forget to handle format.json {...} ?), and check that the conditional flow doesn't lead it somewhere that doesn't handle that format.